# add n number zero into output of SQL command to enough 5 charactor

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to add n zero into output of this command.

```
SQL> select PACK_RF from batch where ri=80;

   PACK_RF
----------
        40
```

the expected output is : 00040

Answer (score 2):

You could use `LPAD` function from `Oracle`

```
WITH batch AS
(
    SELECT 80 AS ri, 40 AS pack_rf FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 80, 30 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 70, 50 FROM dual
)
SELECT LPAD(pack_rf, 5, '0') 
FROM batch
WHERE ri = 80;
```

Tested in [rextester](https://rextester.com/VIKKHI90043)

In case your `pack_rf` column may have length more than 5, you should use a
`CASE` statements to avoid cutting your result

```
WITH batch AS
(
    SELECT 80 AS ri, 4444440 AS pack_rf FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 80, 40 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 80, 30 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 70, 50 FROM dual
)
SELECT CASE WHEN LENGTH(pack_rf) > 5 THEN TO_CHAR(pack_rf) ELSE LPAD(pack_rf, 5, '0') END AS pack_rf
FROM batch
WHERE ri = 80;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try a padding trick here:

```
select substr('00000' || to_char(PACK_RF), -5, 5)
from batch
where ri = 80;
```

### Demo

I was unsure whether or not the `PACK_RF` column be a number or text.  If the latter, then the call to `TO_CHAR` above is unnecessary, and can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using TO_CHAR with the proper format mask.

```
SQL> select to_char(40, 'FM00000') from dual;


   TO_CHAR(40,'FM00000')
________________________
00040
```

Using LPAD or SUBSTR as suggested in previous answers risk undetectable data loss because the number would be stripped/truncated and no error would be thrown.  Using TO_CHAR with a format mask would prevent this.  If a number greater than the number of characters defined in the format mask is used, then # symbols will be returned indicating that the format mask will not work properly for that number.

```
SQL> select to_char(123456, 'FM00000') from dual;

   TO_CHAR(123456,'FM00000')
____________________________
######
```